# How To Get Form Field Values From A Website Form Which Doesnt Have A DataLayer Using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website which has a lead gen form in it. I only want to extract the email id's from the form rather than all the data. I am using GTM to get the email id's. Here's the code i am using:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var button = document.querySelector('.btn');
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            // Retrieve email value from the input field with name 'email'
            var emailInput = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
            var email = emailInput.value.trim();

            // Push email value to the data layer
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'emailSubmitted',
                'email': email
            });
        });
    });
```

As this code should return a datalayer named emailSubmitted i am getting Click Event only rather than the emailsubmit one.

Comment: Can you check the `button` is really the button you want to add click event listener? The selector seems too general that will get the first `.btn` button element rather than the button inside the form. Better CSS selector would like `form#id button.btn`

Comment: Hey i got the solution. The method i used is extracting the form data from localstorage of the browser and storing this information in a variable.